# CQ Dialog: Possible to provide placeholder in text?

Tags: aem

We have a requirement wherein a section of a page will be part authorable and part dynamic. What I mean by this is "You have 6 visits left out of 16." The 6 and 16 in the sentence are coming from a REST service call but the text "You have...visits left out of.." has to be authorable through dialog. Also, we are using AEM 6.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or is there any other way this can be accomplished ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this solution will help others looking for simple placeholder text for their dialog textfields (OP not so much). Use an emptyText attribute...

```
<dialogText fieldLabel="AEM CLassic UI Text" jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
 name="./nameOfText" emptyText="THIS IS THE PLACEHOLDER" xtype="textfield"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can start by extending `foundation/components/text`, where the user would be expected to enter a valid formatable string (i.e. "You have %d visits left out of %d").

In your component you would be implementing `text.jsp` therefore overriding the default behavior of `foundation/components/text`, in which you can do something like

```
<cq:text property="text" escapeXml="true"
         placeholder="<%= Placeholder.getDefaultPlaceholder(slingRequest, component, null)%>"
         tagName="span"
         tagClass="myformatedmessage" />
```

You use `tagName` and `tagClass` which will wind up putting the formattable text in a `<span class="myformatedmessage">...</span>`. Then use jQuery to find it and populate the format placeholders after getting the data via ajax. All that jQuery code you can probably put into a clientlib folder within the same component you extended.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I think you are looking for replacement or substitution instead of placeholders.

"placeholder" generally refers to display text inside a form input that is displayed until the user enters data in the field (such as hint data).

You generally have 3 options for replacing parts of the data:

- Server-side (prevents page from being cacheable in dispatcher).  Requires parsing authored content & replace some kind of tags with desired REST data, such as "You have ${x} visits left out of ${y} total".  Other ways of "tagging" substitution data could look like "You have %x% visits left out of %y%"
- client-side JavaScript DOM manipulation once REST data returns. ie `$el.html(newDomContentString)`
- client-side JavaScript templates (handlebars, dust, etc).  Takes more initial setup in JS, but generally scales better.